# How to filter words that contain repeated character?

Tags: file, grep, repeat

I've been working on this task that seems pretty simple, but I can't make it work despite reading the man and googling similar questions.

I have a file containing thousands of word, and I need to filter words that ends with 'st', while not containing another repetition of either 's' or 't', ex:

Frost is good.

Toast isn't.

I'm able to filter words with the desired ending with the command:

```
grep -e '[s][t]$' .\file
```

What I'm not able to do is filter words containing repetition of either 's' or 't'.

I tried:

```
grep -E 's{0}'
```

or an inverted search

```
egrep -v '(s)\1{0}' .\file
```

*With this one, I only get words that do not contain S at all.

and

```
egrep -v '(s)\1{1}' .\file
```

* This one does nothing, since I get words with the repetition of the 's' character.

Anyone know how I could pipe the `grep -e '[s][t]$' .\file` command into another regular expression that would filter out words containing the repetition of either 't' or 's'?

Thanks.

Comment: `grep '^[^st]*st$' file`? This will match lines that have no `s` nor `t` but having `st` at the end.

Comment: While this command does the trick, doesn't it just filter out words that starts by the character 's'  or 't' while having the 'st' ending? I need to filter out the words  that might contain a repetition of 's' or 't' in the middle too or simply, repetition in the word.

Comment: `'^[^st]*st$'` will match lines like `abcst` and will not return lines like `asbcd` or `atast`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
grep '^[^st]*st$' file
```

This will return lines that match

- `^` - start of string
- `[^st]*` - 0 or more chars other than `s` and `t`
- `st` - `st` substring
- `$` - at the end of the string.